# OSError with Hugging Face: couldn't connect to hugging face

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface, zeroshot-classification

I'm trying to use

```
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model='facebook/bart-large-mnli')
```

[image: image of the code]

But I get this error:

> OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this
> file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like
> facebook/bart-large-mnli is not the path to a directory containing a
> file named config.json.
>
> Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in
> offline mode at
> 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.

[image: image of the error]

I tried to re-connect and change the internet connection, and also tried to run the codes on cloud based envrionments, but the same error message appeared.

Comment: Please post the code and error as a text, not a screenshot.

Comment: If you are on an organization network, you can try another connection. Else try after upgrading the transformers library.